# Does anyone know how to retrieve the list of tasks in Camunda 8, without using tasklist?

Tags: camunda, zeebe

I am currently evalauting Camunda, having previously used version 7 in the past which seems to be significantly more open source than version 8.

I am aware that tasklist and an official tasklist-api exist, however they are only permitted during development and testing without a license.

In Bernd Rücker's medium post [How Open is Camunda Platform 8?](https://blog.bernd-ruecker.com/how-open-is-camunda-platform-8-97d46068e3b1), there is a section:

> A path to production with source-available software
>
> ...
>
> Additionally, you will need to find solutions to replace the tools you cannot use.
>
> Tasklist
>
> You will need to implement your own task management solution based on using workers subscribing to Zeebe [as described in the docs](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/user-tasks/). That also means you have to build your own persistence to allow task queries, as the Tasklist API is part of the Tasklist component and is not free for production use.

I have tried to search the [zeebe](https://github.com/camunda/zeebe) source for any hints, but the only job/task related APIs I seem to be able to find are:

- [activateJobs](https://github.com/camunda/zeebe/blob/main/gateway/src/main/java/io/camunda/zeebe/gateway/GatewayGrpcService.java#L53-L59)
- [completeJob](https://github.com/camunda/zeebe/blob/main/gateway/src/main/java/io/camunda/zeebe/gateway/GatewayGrpcService.java#L69-L75)

I do not believe that these could be the endpoints that tasklist uses as the jobs have to be manually claimed by user interaction from the UI.

Does anyone know how this is achieved?

Comment: Even though you may not like the effort the answer implies, please accept my answer as it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your own zeebe exporter allows you to export any events the engine produces, such as user task state updates. You could store this information in a data sink of your choice and and implement an API on top of it.
See, e.g. https://camunda.com/blog/2019/05/exporter-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

With tasklist component, we can get the tasks via http posts only. Since graphql is getting retired, camunda provides rest api for the same. Access the toke, send the post request to camunda, fetch the tasks. With camunda basic docs, still we need to work on to find an appropriate solution.Refer camunda integrated Swagger  and https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-tasklist-client-java